# Java cannot find symbol

Tags: java

No entiendo donde esta mi fallo, necesito ayuda porque no compilar el siguiente código:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class M3UF2AC01 { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Escribe el ejercicio obligatorio (1-9): ");
        int num = teclado.nextInt(); teclado.nextLine();

        switch(num) {
        case 1: // -------------------- Ejercicio 1: ----------------------------
        System.out.print("Presiona Enter para saludar :)");
        teclado.nextLine();
        saludo1(); // llamar al metodo

            break;


        case 2: // -------------------- Ejercicio 2: ----------------------------
        System.out.print("Dame un numero: "); // pedir el numero
        int numb = teclado.nextInt();
        cuadrado2(numb); // llamar al metodo
            break;

        case 3: // -------------------- Ejercicio 3: ----------------------------
        System.out.print("Dame el primer numero: "); // pedir los numeros
        int num01 = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Dame el segundo numero: ");
        int num02 = teclado.nextInt();

        System.out.println("La media es: "+media3(num01,num02)); // llamar a la funcion

            break;

        case 4: // -------------------- Ejercicio 4: ----------------------------
        System.out.print("Dame un nombre: "); // pedir los datos
        String nom_4 = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Dame un apellido: ");
        String ape_4 = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Dame un lugar: ");
        String lug_4 = teclado.nextLine();
// llamar al metodo 
            break;
        case 5: // -------------------- Ejercicio 5: --------------------------
        System.out.print("Dame un numero: "); // pedir el numero
        int num9 = teclado.nextInt();
        num_9(num9); // llamar al metodo
            break;
        default:
            System.out.print("El numero introducido no corresponde a ningun ejercicio.");
        }
    }
}
```

El error que me sale es

> cannot find symbol

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. ¿Cuál es el fallo del que hablas? Conviene que pongas en la pregunta el mensaje de error.

Comment: mejora el título de tu pregunta, pues no es indicativo de que problema tienes

Comment: no faltará alguna clase o algo que instanciar (?) que llame a dichos métodos?

Comment: Bienvenido, realiza tus preguntas en base a [ask], modifica tu pregunta.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tu error se debe a que los métodos que tratas de llamar no existen.

Es decir, en ninguna parte de tu código se ve que hayas declarado un

```
private static void saludo1(){}
```

o un

```
public static void saludo1(){}
```

igual cabe hacer notar que los métodos estáticos solamente pueden llamar directamente a otros métodos estáticos, y como main es estático, por ellos tus métodos cuando los agregues deben de llevar el modificador `static`.

Comment: y como puedo hacer que retorne el saludo por pantalla en el ejercicio 1 por ejemplo o en el 4 de pedir datos tipo string

Comment: yo recomendaría que le pidas a quien te haya pasado el código que te lo pase completo esta vez :P